# Intellij regex not matching

Tags: regex, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am searching for occurence of the following code for ae1 to ae99:

```
i.a(ae5, "this.where(T::class.java)");
```

I have tested the following regex pattern online successfully

```
^i\.a\(ae[0-9][0-9]\,\h\"this\.where\(T\:\:class\.java\)\"\);$
```

This does not match on intellij though, how can I match the code?

Edit: Its only working for me online. Intellij and Sublime Text both don't match the pattern

Comment: Your regex [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/zfrTlq/1) online `^i\.a\(ae[0-9]+\,\h\"this\.where\(T\:\:class\.java\)\"\);$` [works](https://regex101.com/r/zfrTlq/2). Look, you have one digit after `ae` but you required two in your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works for 0-9. For 10-99 I am adding [0-9] pattern. On my search I have occurences from 1-99 yet none match on android studio

Comment: try this: `^i\.a\(ae\d+\,\h\"this\.where\(T\:\:class\.java\)\"\);$`

Comment: Replace `\h` with `[ \t]`

Comment: Please attach a screencast of the search process in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works for me:
`^i\.a\(ae[1-9][0-9]?,\h\"this\.where\(T::class\.java\)"\);$`

Or you can use `Find | Search Structurally...` with the following template:

```
i.a($x$, "this.where(T::class.java)")
```

With a text filter on $x$ with this regex: `ae[0-9][1-9]?`.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me with the OP's regex and Wiktor's suggestions in both IDE's.

E.g. IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 EAP:

[image]

If it doesn't work for you in IDEA, try restarting it with **File | Invalidate Caches & Restart**.